# Rank correlation matrix in R

Tags: r

How do I produce a rank correlation matrix in an elegant way in R given a data frame with many columns? I couldn't find a built-in function, so I tried

```
> test=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(5,4,3,2,1))
> cor(rank(test))
```

(only 2 columns for simplicity, real data has 5 columns) which gave

```
> Error in cor(rank(test)) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

I figured that this was because `rank` takes a single vector. So then I tried

```
> cor(lapply(test,rank))
```

to get rank applied to *each column* in the data frame, treating the data frame as a list, which gave the error

```
> supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

and I finally ended up getting something working with

```
> cor(data.frame(lapply(test,rank)))
   x  y
x  1 -1
y -1  1
```

However this seems pretty verbose and ugly. I'm thinking there must be a better way -- if so what?

Comment: Your list/data frame issues would be solved by using `sapply` instead, most likely.

Comment: @joran Thanks that fits with the help on sapply that says it is a simplifying version of lapply, in particular returning the result as a matrix if it can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong -- use the `kendall` method argument for `cor()` instead:

```
R> testdf <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(5,4,3,2,1))  
R> cor(testdf, method="kendall") 
   x  y 
x  1 -1    
y -1  1   
R>
```

From `help(cor)`:

> For `cor()`, if method is `"kendall"` or `"spearman"`, Kendall's tau or
>   Spearman's rho statistic is used to estimate a rank-based measure of
>   association. These are more robust and have been recommended if the
>   data do not necessarily come from a bivariate normal distribution. For
>   `cov()`, a non-Pearson method is unusual but available for the sake of
>   completeness. Note that `"spearman"` basically computes `cor(R(x), R(y))`
>   (or `cov(.,.)`) where `R(u) := rank(u, na.last="keep")`. In the case of
>   missing values, the ranks are calculated depending on the value of
>   use, either based on complete observations, or based on pairwise
>   completeness with reranking for each pair.